# Filter specific message value in logstash

Tags: json, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, grok

i am new to logstash.
I am trying to parse log value and applying filter on value using grok.
The log data is -
{"log":"11:20:15|INFO|config-app: Starting_thread\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-12-19T11:19:15.089894627Z"}

The logstash.conf is-

```
input {
   beats { 
        port =>  5045
        host => "0.0.0.0"
    }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    add_field => { 
        "log1" => "%{log}" 
    }
  }
  grok {
     match => { "%{log1}" => ['(%{TIME:time}\|%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}\|%{USER:microservice_name}(:) %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}'] }
  } 
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
     hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
     user => elastic
     password => yourstrongpasswordhere
     index => "pj"
     }  
   stdout {}
}
```

Tried running the above file but pipeline is not creating in logstash.